# Overwriting PHP if statement

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, overwrite

My company is working on a CRM with the Wordpress plugin CQPIM.
There are two issues with it, but I'll just address one, for now.

The plugin functions off of User Roles, and will show ALL the active projects for anyone with the capability: **cqpim_view_all_projects**.

We need to rewrite the following snippet so that the dashboard only shows the projects assigned to the current user.

**original code: there are no hooks to filters to modify**

```
if(current_user_can('cqpim_view_all_projects')) {
  $index++; ?>
  <li>
    <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#progressbar-<?php echo $project->ID; ?>").progressbar({
          value: <?php echo number_format((float)$pc_complete, 2, '.', ''); ?>
        });
      });
    </script>
    <div class="title">
      <a href="<?php echo $edit_url; ?>"><?php if(!empty($project->post_title)) { echo $project->post_title; } else { _e('Untitled', 'cqpim'); } ?></a>
      <?php echo $project_status; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="progress">
      <div id="progressbar-<?php echo $project->ID; ?>"></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="project_stats">
      <li><span class="project_stat_head"><?php _e('Open Tasks' , 'cqpim') ?></span><span class="project_stat"><?php echo $task_count; ?></span></li>
      <li><span class="project_stat_head"><?php _e('Complete' , 'cqpim') ?></span><span class="project_stat"><?php echo number_format((float)$pc_complete, 2, '.', ''); ?>%</span></li>
      <li><span class="project_stat_head"><?php _e('Deadline' , 'cqpim') ?></span><span class="project_stat"><?php echo $finish_date; ?></span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
<?php
} else {
  $access = false;
  $project_contributors = get_post_meta($project->ID, 'project_contributors', true);
  if(empty($project_contributors)) {
    $project_contributors = array();
  }
  foreach($project_contributors as $contributor) {
    if(!empty($contributor['team_id']) && $assigned == $contributor['team_id']) {
      $access = true;
    }
  }
  if($access == true) {
    $index++; ?>
    <li>
      <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          jQuery("#progressbar-<?php echo $project->ID; ?>").progressbar({
            value: <?php echo number_format((float)$pc_complete, 2, '.', ''); ?>
          });
        });
      </script>
      <div class="title">
        <a href="<?php echo $edit_url; ?>"><?php if(!empty($project->post_title)) { echo $project->post_title; } else { _e('Untitled', 'cqpim'); } ?></a>
        <?php echo $project_status; ?>
      </div>
      <div class="progress">
        <div id="progressbar-<?php echo $project->ID; ?>"></div>
      </div>
      <ul class="project_stats">
        <li><span class="project_stat_head"><?php _e('Open Tasks', 'cqpim'); ?></span><span class="project_stat"><?php echo $task_count; ?></span></li>
        <li><span class="project_stat_head"><?php _e('Complete' , 'cqpim') ?></span><span class="project_stat"><?php echo number_format((float)$pc_complete, 2, '.', ''); ?>%</span></li>
        <li><span class="project_stat_head"><?php _e('Deadline' , 'cqpim') ?></span><span class="project_stat"><?php echo $finish_date; ?></span></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <?php
  }
}
```

**My modified code: it works when in the plugin root, but I would like to update this plugin at some point without losing all my files, so need a way to overwrite the original IF statement**

```
if(current_user_can('cqpim_view_all_projects')) {
  $index++; 
  $access = false;
  $project_contributors = get_post_meta($project->ID, 'project_contributors', true);
  if(empty($project_contributors)) {                                    
    $project_contributors = array();
  }
  foreach($project_contributors as $contributor) {
    if(!empty($contributor['team_id']) && $assigned == $contributor['team_id']) {
      $access = true;
    }
  }
  if($access == true) {
    $index++; ?>
  <li>
    <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#progressbar-<?php echo $project->ID; ?>").progressbar({
          value: <?php echo number_format((float)$pc_complete, 2, '.', ''); ?>
        });
      });
    </script>
    <div class="title">
      <a href="<?php echo $edit_url; ?>"><?php if(!empty($project->post_title)) { echo $project->post_title; } else { _e('Untitled', 'cqpim'); } ?></a>
      <?php echo $project_status; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="progress">
      <div id="progressbar-<?php echo $project->ID; ?>"></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="project_stats">
      <li><span class="project_stat_head"><?php _e('Open Tasks', 'cqpim'); ?></span><span class="project_stat"><?php echo $task_count; ?></span></li>
      <li><span class="project_stat_head"><?php _e('Complete' , 'cqpim') ?></span><span class="project_stat"><?php echo number_format((float)$pc_complete, 2, '.', ''); ?>%</span></li>
      <li><span class="project_stat_head"><?php _e('Deadline' , 'cqpim') ?></span><span class="project_stat"><?php echo $finish_date; ?></span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <?php
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If hooks or actions are not available for this plugin, check if the plugin makes use of the function get_template_part/locate_template or something like it. An example is woocommerce, which uses both actions/filters and locate_template so you can either hook into it or overwrite the templates in the theme folder.

Have you tried asking the developer? The plugin is paid, so it would make sense you have some kind of support there. Ask them to include hooks or the ability to overrule templates in your own theme.

Comment: Unfortunately, this plugin did not utilize those functions ): And yes, we do have support, however, all they've offered was a feature request. I just wanted to see if I could take care of it easily. Doesn't appear that I can...